# Numpy complex array multiplication gives unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is working:

```
In [49]: type([1, 2, 3])
Out[49]: list

In [50]: type(array([1, 2, 3]))
Out[50]: numpy.ndarray

In [52]: 1j*array([1, 2, 3])
Out[52]: array([ 0.+1.j,  0.+2.j,  0.+3.j])
```

When I try to do this on my own list `asdf`:

```
In [46]: type(asdf)
Out[46]: list

In [47]: type(array(asdf))
Out[47]: numpy.ndarray

In [48]: 1j*array(asdf)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-dd0d8b4948e8> in <module>()
----> 1 1j*array(asdf)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'complex' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The multiplication seemed happy with the short list, what could possibly go wrong for `asdf`? It is rather large, 20347 elements, but that shouldn't matter?

Comment: What's the type of the contents of `asdf`? That's the kind of error message you'd get for `1j * numpy.array(['string'])`.

Comment: `type(asdf[0]) -> str`. Thank you. Why doesn't the error message say `'complex' and 'str'`, that would be so much more... correct.

Answer (score 2):

The Python interpreter translates `*` to a call to `__mul__` (or one of its variants).  And in the case of `3 * obj`, it will use the method of the `obj`.

Building on your comment that `asdf` contains strings:

```
In [205]: A=np.array(['A','B','C'])
In [206]: B=np.array([1,2,3])
In [207]: B.__mul__(3)
Out[207]: array([3, 6, 9])
In [208]: A.__mul__(3)
Out[208]: NotImplemented
```

For the array of strings the method returns 'NotImplemented', without saying anything about why.  That probably is why the error message says `numpy.array`, the type of `A`, rather than the `dtype` of `A`.  It's an interpreter error message, not a `numpy` one.

---

There is a version of `multiply` that works with strings:

```
In [213]: np.char.multiply(A,3)
Out[213]: 
array(['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'],
```

But not with complex multipliers.